# Number is not correctly formatted when using variable in the Format function in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

In an MS Access invoice report, the totals are formatted using:

```
=Format([value]; "# ##0,00"" €""")
```

But now there is a new customer,who needs his invoices in dollars. Therefore, I added a column "Currency" to the customer table, with a default value "€" for all customers, except the new customer, where the value is "$".

I updated the totals with this format function:

```
=Format([value];"# ##0,00"" " & [Currency] & """")
```

But now the number is not correctly formatted in the report.

With the old function, it would format numbers like "50 000,00 €", but now it formats the numbers like "50 000 €". It seems to just drop the decimals.

Is it not possible to use a variable in the format code in Access? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought the following would achieve the desired result:

```
=Format([Value],"# ##0.00 " & [Currency])
```

The period as a decimal separator should change automatically depending on the regional settings on the PC on which the report is run.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the Currency field out of the `Format` function, and concatenate it afterwards:

```
=Format([value];"# ##0,00") & [Currency]
```

Regards,